# How to implement a zoomcontrol with a bar and sliding button?

Tags: android, android-camera

The default zoomcontrol button with plus/minus buttons is too ugly and also one can't pick a zoom level by just one click. I want something like this:

- ==================O========================== +

I know I can draw one by myself, just want to know if any existing view can do this.

Comment: Put slider bar in layout and links button on actions. You will need a `onTouchListener` to center ball and `onClickListener\onTouchListener` to both buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are showing a SeekBar.

You can do something like:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layoutSlider" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="180dp" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageLeft" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/imageLeft"></ImageView>
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageRight" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/imageRight"></ImageView>
 <SeekBar android:id="@+id/sliderZoom" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageLeft" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageRight" android:layout_centerVertical="true" style="@style/seekBar"></SeekBar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

or a horizontal LinearLayout would do.

The images to the left and right could also be TextViews if you simply want "-" and "+" symbols.

The seekbar has a OnSeekBarChangeListener to listen for adjustments

```
SeekBar mSliderZoom;
mSliderZoom = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sliderZoom);

mSliderZoom.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
 @Override 
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, Boolean fromUser)
 {
 }
.
.
.
});
```

This will give you something similar to this example which shows a "brightness" slider with left and right images for darkness/brightness: 
[image]